# dummyVars() in r and weird column names in R

Tags: r, caret, dummy-variable

for a dataset similar to the one below, I need N level dummy variables. I use dummyVars() from caret package.
As you can see the column names are ignoring "sep="-"" argument and there are some  dots in the column names rather than < or > signs.

```
df <- data.frame(fruit=as.factor(c("apple", "orange","orange", "carrot", "apple")),
                 st=as.factor(c("CA", "MN","MN", "NY", "NJ")),
                 wt=as.factor(c("<2","2-4",">4","2-4","<2")),
                 buy=c(1,1,0,1,0))
   fruit st  wt buy
1  apple CA  <2   1
2 orange MN 2-4   1
3 orange MN  >4   0
4 carrot NY 2-4   1
5  apple NJ  <2   0

library(caret)
dmy <- dummyVars(buy~ ., data = df, sep="-")
df2 <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = df))
df2
  fruit.apple fruit.carrot fruit.orange st.CA st.MN st.NJ st.NY wt..2 wt..4 wt.2.4
1           1            0            0     1     0     0     0     1     0      0
2           0            0            1     0     1     0     0     0     0      1
3           0            0            1     0     1     0     0     0     1      0
4           0            1            0     0     0     0     1     0     0      1
5           1            0            0     0     0     1     0     1     0      0
```

I am confused why dummyVars() is not converting the actual levels into the parts of the column names and why is it ignoring the separator argument.
I would appreciate  any hint on what I am doing wrong!

EDIT: for the future readers :) ! according to AKRUN's note, the argument below for dataframe() solved the problem.

```
df2 <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = df), check.names = FALSE)
  fruit-apple fruit-carrot fruit-orange st-CA st-MN st-NJ st-NY wt-<2 wt->4 wt-2-4
1           1            0            0     1     0     0     0     1     0      0
2           0            0            1     0     1     0     0     0     0      1
3           0            0            1     0     1     0     0     0     1      0
4           0            1            0     0     0     0     1     0     0      1
5           1            0            0     0     0     1     0     1     0      0
```

Comment: The `sep` argument I guess is the separation delimiter in the output column name and it is changed to `.` with `data.frame` call or you may use `check.names = FALSE` i.e. `data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = df), check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Perhaps you want `library(fastDummies);dummy_cols(df, c("fruit", "st", "wt"), split = "-")` ?